# Bold Y-Tick Label and Every Node Near Coord

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, nodes-near-coords

I can make my `xticklabel` apply `\bfseries`, I can make my `xlabel` and `ylabel` apply `\bfseries`.  For some reason, I cannot seem to get my `yticklabel` to apply this effect.  At least when I compare the "1" in my `xticklabel`, it is clearly different than that in my `yticklabel`.

Fairly related, but happy to split into a 2nd question, is applying the same bold weight to the `every node near coord/.append style`.  I do believe that these values are generated in mathmode, so I am not surprised I was not successful in applying a standard `\bfseries` weight to them.  But if someone could provide a solution to that as well, it would be great.  I did try, based on zero understanding of the inner workings, to use the `etoolbox` package and `\robustify\bfseries` without effect.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%This didn't work either
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\robustify\bfseries
\sisetup{inter-unit-product={}\cdot{},sticky-per=true,multi-part-units=single,%
separate-uncertainty=true,list-units=single,range-units=single,detect-all,%
detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}

\DeclareSIUnit\calorie{cal}
\DeclareSIUnit\kcal{\kilo\calorie}
\DeclareSIUnit\kcalpmole{kcal\per\mole}

\definecolor{hoyemagenta}{HTML}{FF3FFF}
\definecolor{hoyegreen}{HTML}{31FF31}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
%\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error %
%-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && dvips -o "\image".ps %
%"\image".dvi}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        color=white,
        width=450pt,
        ybar, bar shift=0pt, bar width=12,
        enlarge x limits=0.07,
        ylabel={Free Energy Difference (\si{\kcalpmole})},
        xlabel={Trapping Product},
        label style={color=white,font=\bfseries},
        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},
        every axis/.style={color=white},
        ymax=40,
        ymin=-110,
%       I also tried manually setting the ticks, in hopes that would trigger the change        
%       ytick={-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0,20,40},
        xtick pos=left,
        nodes near coords,
        %Here I tried setting \bfseries for my nodes without success
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\bfseries,%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        tick label style={font=\bfseries\Large},       
%        y tick label style={color=white,font=\bfseries},
%       I used to just have this x tick label style line below, then I tried the separate y tick label style
%       and also the tick label style above that
%        x tick label style={anchor=center,yshift=-6pt,color=white,font=\bfseries\large},
        symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
        ]
        \addplot[fill=hoyegreen,]
        coordinates{
        (1,-48.93)
        (3,-13.62)
        (6,-46.85)
        (8,-42.27)
        (10,-55.74)};
        \addplot[fill=hoyemagenta]
        coordinates{        
        (2,-26.90)
        (4,31.78)
        (5,-49.25)
        (7,-49.71)
        (9,-44.14)
        (11,-51.07)};
        \addplot[fill=yellow]
        coordinates{(12,-97.69)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\boldmath` instead of `\bfseries` is sufficient for both questions.

[image]

I would really consider changing the style but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Can you explain what you would design differently?  I do have some requirements, black background and white text are a must.  Everything else is pretty much open to changing.  Also, is there a way to get the text size of the ylabel to match that of the xlabel?  They should look exactly the same font style/size, etc.

Comment: @JM Then nevermind. Those are the ones that I had in mind but if so, there is not much to do. They look pretty much the same to me.

Comment: Yea, it is for a presentation, and the whole template we use are black background, white text.  It has the benefit that when we spot color portions of a slide, colors really pop against the black background.

Comment: @JM There is a nice chapter in beamer manual about this dark background issue ;)

Comment: :)  Yea, I do understand some of those (like the difficulty reading, hence the need for bold text).  But this is a standard requirement I must have.  Any help on that size issue in my first comment?  Can I force "textmode"

Comment: @JM I can't spot the difference. What's the exact property you're wondering about?

Comment: Ok, so the different is really really really really minor.  2/128 of an inch difference in the height of some of the numbers (that was measured off of the "4" in the y axis and x axis ticks, y axis tick is shorter).

Comment: @JM I don't know where the discrepancy is though I still don't see the difference. Maybe it's a rendering issue.